# passing mysql_fetch_array to array()

Tags: php

how can i pass mysql_fetch_array() to array()

Comment: what do you mean pass? what exactly are you trying to accomplish? mysql_fetch_array() already returns an array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

did you mean:

```
$variable = mysql_fetch_array($result); //$variable is now an array
```

Answer (score 17):

If you want to use it for multiple results you may want to assign within the while statement. Such as

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");
$resultSet = array();
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    $resultSet[] = $result;
}
```

Comment: That was awesome, I used this to convert mysql result to array while I can also save result to json to minimize mysql server usage

Answer (score 4):

A shorter version to add multiple results into an array with a while statement

```
while($r[]=mysql_fetch_array($query));
array_pop($r); // mysql_fetch_array() moves the internal data pointer ahead so last row should be cut off
```

Answer (score 0):

mysql_fetch_array() is just a function that outputs an array, so you can simply attach it to any variable, like so:

```
$foo = mysql_fetch_array($bar);
```